# Why does chrome have a border around my page header, but it does not appear in other browsers (such as EI)

Tags: google-chrome, wordpress-theming

The header on my website appears to have a mysterious 1px black border in chrome that does not appear in other browsers like IE. Is there a CSS change I can make that will remove it when displayed in Chrome?

Link: http://tinyurl.com/stwcfe

Comment: Many thanks @Digital-Frankenstein! I had added code to support WordPress Custom Headers, but needed to add a check that the custom header image was set.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an empty img tag in your header element.
Remove that and it disappears.